# Basic Pyspark Question - If Else Equivalent

Tags: select, pyspark

Hi very basic question but I am new to Pyspark. I want my function to return different columns based on input argument but can't figure out how to do this. The Python equivalent would be:

`if model='a': return df[[colA,colB]] if model ='b': return df[[colA,colB,colC]]`

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pyspark equivalent would be to use [select](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.select.html) to fetch the required columns -

```
if model = 'a':
   return df.select(*[colA,colB])
elif model = 'b':
   return df.select(*[colA,colB,colC])
```

Comment: From reading online it seems like if and elif can not be used in pyspark though. I am seeing examples of people using the when function but the context they are using it in is to add a new column which I am not doing here

Comment: Nothings stopping you to include an if else within a pyspark code , consider it similar to python , however differences exists in the way you interact with a `Spark DataFrame`

Answer (score 0):

You can always implement if else logic in pyspark similar to python. You can also use if elif else etc as applicable in python. Including while and for loop but that all depends on your requirement and what you want to do with the logic.

```
if res_flag=="Model 1":
    return df.select('colA','colB')
elif res_flag=="Model 1":
    return df.select('colA','colB','colc')
else:
    return df
```